Flutter doesn’t start
@Ultranmus Now i have this error. I had flutter stop working when I added firebase to this project. I even tried creating new flutter projects, they don't work either, but they have a different error. I've already searched everywhere for a solution to this issue, I can't find anything anywhere.
problem here
I have already updated gradle and flutter. I don't know what the problem

please add code not code images.... include settings.gradle and build.gradle code as well.

Your demo GitHub repo link not working

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
